# How long does a transfer take

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I made a few transfers from a btc free mining app 4 times each for 500000 satoshi and it said it would take 10 days to show up in my coinbase wallet, but nothing yet.can I somehow track the transactions so I don't lose 2000000 satoshi?

Answer (score 3):

Transfers in bitcoin can take anywhere from a few minutes to a few days depending on the network status and the fee paid. Currently, it's closer to a few minutes. In either case, you can also usually view unconfirmed transactions in your wallet or on block explorers such as [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/).

In your case, however, things seem unlikely. All such apps that I've ever heard of (free mining, free btc, etc.) are scams, and never actually pay you. They will simply claim the withdrawal is pending, or keep telling you that you are under the withdrawal limit, while using your device for ads, or other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

> a btc free mining app

What's that? A "btc free mining app" sounds like **a scam**. Mining on a mobile phone is terribly unprofitable and I don't think that you really made 2000000 (0.02 BTC => 100$) with a mobile phone.